# Why Ember.js API method TransitionTo in Route Class is private?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here's [link](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) from Ember API. Why is private. That's mean, that I shouldn't use it in my production?

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the meaning of `private`, the Ember API page is referring to what functions the Ember API can call *within your code*. The definition of `public` and `private` methods is the same in *every* programming language, and their scope is also similar:

- `private` - These methods can only be accessed within the method's class, for example, you cannot call the private method named `transitionTo` from the `Ember.ArrayProxy` class. You can however call `transitionTo` from a function or procedure *inside* the `Ember.Route` class.
- `public` - These methods can be accessed from anywhere in your code, for example you will be able to call the public method named `addObserver` from any other class, hence the name 'public'

---

It should also be noted that use of some methods are discouraged; such methods are prefixed with an `_` underscore.
These methods may be outdated, or generally be unsafe to use.

Thanks to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166409/daniel) for suggesting I add that in.

Comment: But why this method [transitionTo] is not `protected`? We can call method transitionTo from extended classes, too.

Comment: @underoot It's not `protected` to enable you to call it from extended classes, but that goes outside the scope of your question.